# Docmd.Runquery Access - Expected Function or variable error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a SQL query in Access that looks like this:

```
SELECT Max(pluquo) AS Expr1 
FROM SYNC002_ACCESS;
```

I run this query, it is working I have my result.
What I am trying to do is assign the result of that query to a Text Box.
I am trying to do that by right click on the text box -> Build Event -> and writing a code in VBA.

What I though it would be a simple task, it isn't for me at least. The code in VBA looks like:

```
Private Sub Text5_Click()

Me.Text5 = DoCmd.OpenQuery("MAX_PLUQUO")

End Sub
```

I tried also:

```
Private Sub Text5_Click()

Me.Text5.Value = DoCmd.RunSQL("SELECT MAX(pluquo) FROM SYNC002_ACCESS")

End Sub
```

What ever I try I always get an error message saying: "Compile error: Expected Function or variable"

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openquery), the `OpenQuery` method of the `DoCmd` object will either open a `select` query in datasheet view (in the same way as you might by double-clicking on the query in MS Access), or will run an action query - this method will **not** return the results of a query.

To populate a form control with the result of your query, you can either open the query as a recordset and assign the value held by the first record to your control, e.g.:

```vb
With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT MAX(pluquo) AS Expr1 FROM SYNC002_ACCESS")
    Me.Text5 = !Expr1
    .Close
End With
```

(No `EOF` check is required since `select max()` will always return a record, even for an empty dataset)

Or alternatively, you can obtain the maximum value using the [DMax](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/dmin-dmax-functions-f5c6de87-8752-4f29-ab4b-c554053d299f?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) domain aggregrate function:

```vb
Me.Text5 = DMax("pluquo","SYNC002_ACCESS")
```